# Unusable HDD and wrong 'Power-On hours' of S.M.A.R.T

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

Recently (last month) I bought a 120GB Maxtor (Model: 6L120P0) Hard disk drive and and now, I can not even format or re-partition it and I understood that there are some bad sectors on the disk. So I tried to fix the problem and I tested below methods but no result:

- HDD Regenerator to cover bad sectors;
- EaseUS Partition Master to format and it was successful but I couldn't use HDD again;
- Parted Magic bootable disk to format drive;
- Windows built-in utilities like CHKDSK (and it says that there is no problem).

I tried to get "Power-On hours" of SMART and in vary programs (HDD Tune, GsmartControl, CrystalDisk Info  (with a ? symbol at the end of attribute) and etc).

What should I do? How can I reformat this new (or maybe old) HDD?

note that I'm using this drive under Windows 7 32bit pro.

Comment: Why bother wasting time on a drive that old? It’s slow and small and, well, old.

Comment: @DanielB you right, but I'm just trying to know these things (like why they happened, how should be fixed and you know, etc.) SMART attribute is a fixed thing (isn't it?) and should be same in all of these valid programs, but why it's not? O.o

Comment: Well, unless you show us the actual values these programs display, we can’t judge them. ;)

Comment: Oops, you right again. I'll edit the question as soon as I arrive home.